# Activity is not starting

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-dialog

Please have a look at the following code

**Form.java**

My main activity is Form.java. Inside that, I have an `AlertDialog`. When the user clicks on the "yes" button, the following class will be called

```
private class PositiveDialogBtnAction implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {

        public PositiveDialogBtnAction()
        {
        }  
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseConnector.getStreetAddress(selectedBranch), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Select a Phone Number");

            dialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Following are the XML file and the Java class, which is being set to a `Dialog` inside `PositiveDialogBtnAction` class mentioned above.

**activity_call_dialog**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/callNumber1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/callNumber2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="" />
```

**CallDialog.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallDialog extends Activity {

    private DatabaseConnector database = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();
    private TextView ph1,ph2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_dialog);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //String selectedBranch = Form.selectedBranch;

        //ph1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.callNumber1);
        //ph2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.callNumber2);

        //ph1.setText(database.getPhoneNumber1(selectedBranch));
        //ph2.setText(database.getPhoneNumber2(selectedBranch));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_call_dialog, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

But, when the `PositiveDialogBtnAction` is fired, The `Toast` mentioned in `CallDialog.java` never get fired. It seems like it is not dealing with `CallDIalog.java.` Because of that, I am unable to set the values to the text fields in **activity_call_dialog.xml** as well. I have commented out those lines.

Why this Java file bundled with this activity is not getting called? Please help!

Comment: Could you clean up your code a bit. It's really noisy and very hard to see what is going on. E.g. you mention Call.java but that is not show anywhere. Also, remove unnecessary commented lines... Maybe creating a Gist and keeping only the relevant code here would be a better solution.

Comment: @allprog: I mentioned about CallDialog.java, that was a typo. Sorry. I corrected it

Comment: Is `CallDialog` supposed to be an `Activity` or `Dialog`? If you want it to be a dialog, it shouldn't extend `Activity`. Also, you never instantiate it. You just create a new `Dialog`, not a new `CallDialog`. If it's supposed to be an `Activity`, you need to start it with an `Intent`, not by creating a dialog and showing it.

Comment: would you show me your `Form.java` class, you can handle the positive and nigative clicks easier than that, and please edit your question, your classes aren't clear

Answer (score 0):

For creating the alert dialog you should use the AlertDialog.Builder. It has a beautiful fluent interface that makes it really easy to handle dialogs. Example:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Someone is calling you")
    .setPositiveButton("Positive", 
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.CallDialogActivity"));
            }})
    .create()
    .show();
```

In order to start a new activity from inside the click listener, simply call `startActivity()` with the action registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for you CallDialog (I suggest you rename it to *CallDialogActivity*). But anyway, you should determine where you use dialogs or activities. They have to be handled accordingly.